# Create JSON File Serializing the class in Java

Tags: java, json, pdf, serialization

I have the following class:

```
public class PDFValues {
    private String value;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;

    public PDFValues(){

    }

    public PDFValues(String value, int x, int y){
        this.setValue(value);
        this.setX(x);
        this.setY(y);
    }

    public void setValue(String value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setX(int x){
        this.xPos = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y){
        this.yPos = y;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return this.xPos;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return this.yPos;
    }
}
```

And then I want to do this:

```
public class PDFtoJSONTest {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<PDFValues> listaElementos = new ArrayList<PDFValues>();

        listaElementos.add(new PDFValues("Anubis Lockward Botello",
                           new Integer(100), new Integer(633)));

        ....more code

    }

}
```

What I want to do, is save all the PDFValues in the ArrayList, as a JSON file, but I don't know how to make it automatic, I thought of Serializing the object or something, but I can't find a solution to this and I'm not sure how I could make the PDFValues object serializable.

I want to do this to save those values in a JSON file and then use them as properties to generate a PDF file, I'm using PDFBox for the generation of the PDFs files and SimpleJSON for the .json ones.

I'm working on a project where I'd have to generate thousands of pdf files out of some processed data. I've already managed to parse the data which consists of about 500+ MBs of text and holds around five thousand account statements which need to be generated as PDFs.

The thing is, that seeings as the Text data is generated in PDFs, one needs to indicate the position of the starting character in a string to PDFValues, to generate a PDFTextInfo object and then add it to the PDF, the file would need to contain images and text and other stuff.

Note: If there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I'm open to suggestions, but I'd also like an answer to what I'm trying to do, and know if it would work or not, and why for both cases.

I'd like to make my code as fast as possible, right now I'm able to process the whole TXT file from RAW to mostly clean data in under 2 minutes and I know it might be optimized but right now that's not the point :D

I'd like to generate the PDFs files as fast as possible, but I've been working with that project in Java for like 1 1/2 months now, and I've only learned about JSON and PDF file generation in the past week...it's been three days of working on the JSON file and I'm a bit lost.

Here's an example of the file output for the JSON file that I'm trying to accomplish, this one I generated it manually and I managed to read and process the file, now I'm trying to generate it automatically:

{
    "Header": {
        "FullName": 
        {
            "Name":"Anubis Lockward Botello",
            "Horizontal":180,
            "Vertical":633
        },
        ..... more elements .....
    }
}

As you can see, I'm trying to divide the elements on the pdf files as if they were panels, like HEADER, BALANCES, TRANSACTIONS and stuff, and build the PDF file as if they were pieces of a puzzle, but right now I'm trying to "build" the name element on the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess there is a better way to do build PDF files than writing and then re-reading a file, but I can provide one answer for your JSON question.

Use the Apache [commons-lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) library and look into `ToStringBuilder`. You can then define a `toString()` method on your object and use the built-in `ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE` format. You'd then have to wrap your list of PDFValues in some other object that can store a PDFValue for Header, FullName, etc..

```
    @Override
public String toString() {

    return new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE)
            .append("Name", value)
            .append("Horizontal", xPos)
            .append("Vertical", yPos)

            .toString();
}
```

I should note that you could pull in [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or similar libraries, annotate your objects with the required `JsonProperty` annotations and use the library to serialize your object to JSON as you would for REST or similar. But, for a simple use case like yours, the `ToStringBuilder` is simple and effective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, what would be a better way to build a PDF file? I know that writing and then generating it from reading another file might be kind of slow, but I can't find an answer of a better way...I know there has to be one

Comment: I have not done PDF generation in a while, and I can't recall the name of the library I used at the time (edit: it was [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). I believe it was an open source project, but I'm sure there are a few libraries that could handle that. 

Look into [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) or [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org) and see if they work for your PDF needs.

Comment: I said that I was using PDFBox lol, anyways, I don't know of a better way to generate de PDF files, anyways, thanks a lot for your help, I found a way to apply what you suggested, I created the ToStringBuilder inside the toString method, and now I'm gonna use a decorator to "wrap" the values inside the elements, and then put that inside a "container"...I'll post the code with the solution, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

OK, I managed to get this far thanks to JudgingNotJudging, what I did was taking his answer and applying a Decorator Pattern to the object, so that I have a PDFValue, that's inside a PDFElement, that's part of a PDFContainer, so it goes like this:

```
Header: (this is our PDFContainer)
  FullName: (so, Header HAS-A FullName element)
    PDFValue: (and FullName HAS-A a PDFValue, that has the Name or value to be   shown, and the X and Y coordinates inside the PDF)
```

Here's the code:

The PDFValue class is still the same, and I added the overridden toString() method according to JudgingNotJudging's answer.

```
public class PDFValuesDecorator extends PDFValues{

}
```

In PDFValuesDecorator we don't do anything, we're just going to extend PDFValues so that we have the correct type of the class we want to add behavior to, and still get a common type for all the different classes we might create this way.

```
public class PDFElement extends PDFValuesDecorator {
    private PDFValues pdfValue;
    private String elementID;

    public PDFElement(PDFValues pdfValue, String elementID){
        this.pdfValue = pdfValue;
        this.elementID = elementID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {      
        return new ToStringBuilder(this, ToStringStyle.JSON_STYLE)
                .append(elementID, pdfValue.toString())
                .toString();
    }

}
```

In the constructor we save the instance of the object we're trying to "wrap" so that we can "add" something to it. In this case, we're adding an ID for the element and we're modifying the toString() method of the element to also include the toString() method of the PDFValue, so that they both show both of their values in the appropriate order.

Finally, here's my main method:

```
public class PDFtoJSONTest {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<PDFValues> listaElementos = new ArrayList<PDFValues>();

        PDFValues name = 
                new PDFValues(
                               "Anubis Lockward Botello",
                               new Integer(100), 
                               new Integer(633)
                             );

        PDFElement fullName = new PDFElement(name, "FullName");
        PDFElement header = new PDFElement(fullName, "Header");

        listaElementos.add(header);

        for(PDFValues value : listaElementos){              
            System.out.println("Valor: " + value.toJSONString());           
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first thing I do is create an ArrayList of PDFValues, then I create a single object for the name value, then that name is wrapped inside the FullName element, and then that's stored inside a Header element. As you can see, I can pass around the List object and do with it whatever I want.

And also, I could create other PDFElements like images and stuff, and I can save all of them inside the ArrayList and pass them around and then when I want to save them, I just have to call the toString method once and I would get the correct output, btw, here's the resulting value from the JSON string:

```
Valor: {"Header":"{"FullName":"{"Name":"Anubis Lockward Botello","Horizontal":100,"Vertical":633}"}"}
```